# How to extend class which is in another Directory?

Tags: php, class

I have a class called **SeleniumUtility** and try to extend **PortalController** (just for test).

[image]

I tried it like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Utility;

require_once(__DIR__.'/../Controllers/PortalController.php');

class SeleniumUtility extends PortalController
{
...
```

However, I get `FatalErrorException in SeleniumUtility.php line 14:
Class 'App\Http\Utility\PortalController' not found`

So it still tries to search in Utilty folder.

How does it work?

Comment: Make sure your Class name in `PortalController.php` is `PortalController`

Comment: Is your parent class name like you extend (Extend class name should be same case). Is this project namespace based?

Comment: @B. Desai, yes the class name is `PortalController`, I just checked it

Comment: @MizanurRahmanKhan, yes I am using namespaces. In PortalController.php I use `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` and in SeleniumUtilty I use `namespace App\Http\Utility;`

Comment: Do you have a PSR-4 compliant autoloader? See my answer.

Comment: I don't know how I can find this out.

Comment: Search for information about your framework, if it is one of the popular ones. I have never used a PHP framework made by someone else. There might be a `config` folder. Look for an `autoloader.php` file. On UNIX / Linux? Try using `grep` on your file structure for `autoloader` or `PSR-4`. Or, try using the `find` command on your file structure. I have confidence you can find the answer. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have an autoloader, such as a [PSR-4 autoloader](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), you can implement the `use` syntax.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Utility;

use App\Http\Controllers\PortalContoller as PortalController;

class SeleniumUtility extends PortalController
{
```

...

Answer (score 2):

According to you are using namespace change your code as below:

```
namespace App\Http\Utility;

require_once(__DIR__.'/../Controllers/PortalController.php');
use App\Http\Controllers as Controllers;
class SeleniumUtility extends Controllers\PortalController
{
```

Comment: PSR-2 for standardization can be a good thing here. http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#overview

Comment: He probably will not need a `require_once` statement if he has an autoloader.

Comment: Yes I don't need `require_once`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use like this.

```
class SeleniumUtility extends \App\Http\Controllers\PortalController
{

}
```

or

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PortalController;
class SeleniumUtility extends PortalController
{

}
```

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer.

Comment: @Loko I am really curious. So why?